# PyTorch memory does not return to the OS after the related QThread is finined in QT

Tags: python, pytorch, pyside6

I am trying to create a interface to control a deep learning program. I use a second thread by QThread to train the model. And I use a stop button to stop the training thread. After I pressed the stop button, the thread is actually finished, but the GPU memory is not released.
My code of the two buttons:

```
def start_training(self):
    self.train_thread = run_training()
    self.train_thread.start()

# thread确实被停止，但pytorch的显存占用没有交还给OS
def stop_training(self):
    self.train_thread.cfg['training'] = False

    time.sleep(2)
    print('is running:', self.train_thread.isRunning())
    print('finished:', self.train_thread.isFinished())
```

```
class run_training(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = {'training': True}

    def run(self):
        training(self.cfg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    scf = SolarCellForm()
    scf.main_ui.show()
    app.exec()
```

The training program:

```
def training(cfg):
    net = ResNet(depth=50, num_classes=10).cuda().train()

    while cfg['training']:
        inp = torch.randn((1, 3, 512, 512), dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
        target = torch.tensor([1], dtype=torch.int64).cuda()
        out = net(inp, target)
```

After I pressed the stop button:

[image]

But the GPU memory which is needed for training is still occupied.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a test again. The memory is used by the CUDA context. Only if the total script is exited, the memory would be returned to the OS. It should have nothing to do with `QThread`. Here is a related question. (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-do-not-clear-gpu-memory-when-return-to-another-function/125944)